# How to determine which form controls the keyboard input on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, input, keyboard, controls

I'm developing a VB.net windows application and I have some issues with the keyboard input.

My application has different forms and I'm showing and hidding them with the user interaction. One of the inputs comes from the keyboard, and here is where I have a problem.

When I hide a form and show the next one, most of the times the new-shown form does not receive the keyboard input until I click somewhere on it.

I assume that the problem is that the new form I'm showing is not the "selected application" for windows until the user interacts with it by clicking on it, but I don't know how to set this "property" by code.

I tried with focus and select on the whole form (Me.select/focus) and in some form's control (me.lbl_xxx.select/focus), but I did not get any result.

Can anyone explain me how to control which application/form gets the keyboard input on windows?

Thanks
David

Comment: Do you just hide the forms, or do you unload and close them?

Comment: I have all forms created and all I do is hide/show them and setting Topmost property in the visible one. I can not kill and create every time the form because of the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really interact with a label so the input focus won't be set properly.
Focussing a specific textbox on your form on the other hand should just work fine.